# Rationalization of an integer set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}^2$ be the set $\{(x,y) \, : \, y \text{ is the greatest power of 2 dividing } x\}$. I'm wondering how the set gets when multipled by the non negative rationals, i.e. what is $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}X$?

Comment: "How the set gets"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:**
$$\mathbb Q_{\ge 0}X = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Q_{>0}^2\mid \frac xy\in 2\mathbb N-1\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$$

*Proof:*

"$\supseteq$":
Clearly $(0,0)= 0\cdot (1,1)\in \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}X$ becuse $(1,1)\in X$. Let $x,y,$ be positive rational numbers such that $k:= \frac xy$ is an odd natural number. Then $(k,1)\in X$ and $y\cdot(k,1)=(x,y)\in\mathbb Q_{\ge 0}X$.

"$\subseteq$": Let $(n,m)\in X$ and $q\in \mathbb Q_{\ge0}$. If $q=0$, then $q\cdot(n,m)=(0,0)$ and we are done.
Otherwise, $q=\frac rs$ for suitable natural numbers $r,s$. Also, we have $m=2^k$ with $k\in\mathbb N_0$ and $n=um$ with $u$ an odd natural number. Note that $q\cdot(n.m)=(x,y)$ with $x=qn$, $y=qm$.
Then $x>0$ and $y>0$ because $q$, $n$ and $m$ are positive.
Moreover, $\frac xy=\frac{n}{m}=u$ is an odd natural number, i.e. an element of $2\mathbb N-1$.$_\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind giving a short explanation? Or just an intuition?